# Laravel - Email takes 5 minutes to get delivered

Tags: laravel, email, delay

I don't know if this is Laravel related or not, but it is the first time it happenes and I never had this with other websites.

When a user registers, a Email is sent out for email confirmation. This email shows up in the inbox only 5 minutes later.. but the "sent" time is correct, so it appears that the email is sent properly, but stops somewhere for some reason for 5 minutes.. I keep getting reports by users "hey I did not get the confirmation email" and a few minutes later "hey never mind just got it..."

what could be the reason for this?

email config:

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.xxx.com
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=yyy@xxx.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=admin@xxx.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Comment: please share what is your email config

Comment: updated post. thank oyu

Comment: could be your SMTP server that has delay - try using the SMTP manually from outlook or another client. If you believe your application can be the problem, you can change the mailer to log or array and check the response directly